# Are female gang members also hoes?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I've been working on some assassination missions, and started tracking *The Big Time, Baby*.[image: Assassination description].

I went into Espina, and started killing a bunch of Morningstar members.  I got up to a 5-star notoriety with them, so I certainly believe I had fulfilled that part of the task.[image: 5-star notoriety]

While killing the morningstar, I killed a bunch of the female members.  I don't want to judge, but they seem pretty ho-ish to me.[image: Female gang members].

Even after killing members for a solid few minutes, no target popped up.  I'm assuming that the female gang members are not the hos I'm looking for, but I didn't find anyone looking less lady-like than the female morningstar members.

Do female morningstar members count as hos?  If not, where can I find hos in Espina?

Comment: *These aren't the hos you're looking for.*

Comment: @GnomeSlice Good catch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, those are not hos.  It's tricky to both kill people and gang members, because after a certain "gang wanted" (or police wanted) rating normal civillians stop spawning.  Also, having high police notoriety keeps gang members from spawning, and vice versa.

Find a group of Morningstar gang members, and anger them, and then go around killing hos while keeping your gang rating above one star.  When you start to get to around 3 police notoriety, back off on the civilians and max out Morningstar.

As far as actually enacting this plan, I found for this one the easiest thing to do was roll up in a tank.  Just destroy the heck out of every civillian and gang member you come across, and he'll show up pretty quickly.  I couldn't tell you if I managed to kill many or few hos, I just wiped out as many civilians as I could and hoped that somewhere among the bodies were some.

Many of the assassination missions have opaque or downright odd requirements, and I don't find that they are 100% accurate, either.