# What is a "no-weapon kill?"

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I've been trying to clear out the Saints Book, and I was working on Angel's "No-Weapon Kill" challenge.

[image: No-Weapon Kill Challenge Description]

I assumed this was simple, and I'd go up to cops/gangs and punch the crap out of them for a bit and get it.  But, as [this album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29Esl.jpg) attests to, I beat up the cops for a while.  When I checked my progress on the challenge, though, I was still at 14/25 kills.

Clearly, at some point through playing the game, I've gotten 14 kills the game considers "no-weapon" kills, but I have no idea what I would have done to get them to count.  I would have thought at least the wrestling moves would count, since that's what Angel would have wanted, but I made absolutely no progress towards the challenge.

What the heck does the game mean by a "no-weapon kill?"

Comment: I'm fairly certain you have to use your fists and the primary attack combos, no using the quicktime heavy attacks. Not sure though so I can't answer, and I can't be bothered to start a new game to test.

Comment: @MrSmooth I tried straight up punching, the wrestling moves, the quicktime things, and the nut punches.  None of them seem to have worked, which is irritating.

Comment: Yeah, it seemed weird for me too. I wasn't getting them for the quicktime moves, I got them sometimes from regular combos and got them sometimes from using a weapon (gun, not melee weapon) and just pressing the melee button. But no matter what I did, it was never consistent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No-weapon kills are just as you say - they're kills you make only with your fists.  Any other melee weapon or gun will disqualify you.  You can feel free to do wrestling moves, but I'd avoid the "nut assault" move, as I think that puts you in a different category of kill.  Some of the melee moves also cause you to draw your weapons, even if you didn't intend to, so watch out for that.

I believe though, that you will have to do this against rival gang members.  Several of these challenges distinguish between rival gang members and everyone else, even though they don't say so specifically.

Some of these moves will pop a little "respect circle" in the upper right corner of the HUD.  I didn't see one for no-weapon kills on either gang members or police officers just now, so I'd just go kill a gang member with your fists and verify that the count is going up.  You'll also see a "challenge progress" popup every so often, so keep an eye out for that.  I think getting to 15 should make it show up.

Comment: So it doesn't count against police officers?  I had assumed that the game counted the police as a gang for the purpose of such statistics.  I guess I'll have to investigate by punching up some [hoes](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42489/are-female-gang-members-also-hoes)

Comment: I feel like it *should* but it sounds like you're doing it right, so that's what I'd suggest as a test just to make sure.  The count of these needed is so low, I never did that much investigation.

Comment: I'll add that I didn't use the quicktime event route for my no-weapon kills, but I don't know if that disqualifies you or not.  I think you get credit for a "beatdown" in that case, but I'm not certain if that is or is not considered a no-weapon kill.

Answer (score 3):

I used to be confused by the requirements for this challenge until I found that only gang members count. Also, knock down kills conflicts with no-weapon kills (and don't count as the latter).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to use left click, left click, right click to kill the gang members. Or equivalently for consoles light attack, light attack, heavy.